# How to extract month and year from a datetime series and store them into two separate columns?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, one-liner

I have a dataframe with a `Date` column that has datetime objects in it. I can extract the month and year from the `Date` column and store them in columns of the respective names using the code below.

```
df["Month"] = df["Date"].dt.month
df["Year"] = df["Date"].dt.year
```

But is there a way to do this in just one line?

Comment: Achieving the result in one line is probably going to be a lot less readable than what you already have

Comment: `df['Month'], df['Year'] = df["Date"].dt.month, df["Date"].dt.year`

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish Okay that's one good way to keep it both readable and one line...now I feel dumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
df['Month'], df['Year'] = df["Date"].dt.month, df["Date"].dt.year
```